# iBooks Author on iMac 10.13. Preview on iPad not available

Tags: ipad, ibooks-author

In iBooks Author, the preview on iPad option is not working. I have tried 2 different iPads on all ports and my iPhone, but it is still greyed out and not available. What could be wrong?